# Is it possible to use a DDR2 Ram Chip on the PI as a pager file?

Tags: memory

simple, I have a few old DDR2 RAM chips laying around, and would like to use the Ram chips for a pager file on my PI. is this possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible - considering DDR2 Ram has 240 pins, it's not likely the 40 available on the raspberry pi are enough - and that's just the physical number of pins ... the actual functionality required to access DDR2 Ram is far beyond what is possible with the Pi's GPIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a ram disk (not a disk in the ram, a ram as a disk) and convert its SATA output to USB. But you will be limited to the USB speed and maybe you will need to feed it with additional power (maybe with a USB hub that has external power supply).

Thus, It **is possible** but I think it is **not practical or efficient**.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/251694/is-dimm-to-usb-convertor-available

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it is not possible to use DDR2 RAM with a Raspberry Pi.

If you need swapfile, use a USB hard drive or USB SSD as that's fast enough to allow swapping.